# Variable not found in library when importing with CFFI

Tags: python, python-cffi, cffi

I am trying to load the following .h file:

```
3 typedef struct {
4     uint8_t clock_pin;
5 } pinout;
6 
7 pinout foo = {.clock_pin = 5};
8 pinout bar = {.clock_pin = 4};
```

Using the following python file:

```
1 from pathlib import Path
2 import cffi
3 
4 FFI = cffi.FFI()
5 
6 with open(str(Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('lib', 'pins', 'pinout.h'))) as f:
7     FFI.embedding_api(''.join([line for line in f if not line.startswith('#')]))
8 
9 PINOUT = FFI.dlopen('c')
```

When I try to get foo I get the following error:

```
>>> PINOUT.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/cmp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 802, in <lambda>
    lambda self: read_variable(BType, name),
KeyError: "variable 'foo' not found in library 'libc.so.6': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined symbol: foo"
```

It's worth noting that I have the exact same set up for another header file where I define an enum, and can address the individual elements of the enum using the same notation I tried using here.

Comment: Unsure what you're asking for.  The C syntax ``pinout foo = <...>;`` declares a global variable called ``foo``.  CFFI expects to find this global variable in the C library.  But there is no such thing.

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that an enum is purely a declaration, and not something actually found inside compiled C libraries, unlike global variables and the implementation of functions.